# I'm stuck on p:Tabmenu help please

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using p:tabMenu component. I have 4 menuitems, each one redirects to a different jsf page but the problem is that the page is returned without changing the activeindex and activeindex remains same with the initial value which is 0.

this code is on a template page for all pages

```
<h:form>
    <p:tabMenu activeIndex="0">
        <p:menuitem value="Home" url="Menu.jsf" icon="ui-icon-star" />
        <p:menuitem value="Fabricants" url="/pagess/pagesFabricant/Fabricant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-wrench"  />  
        <p:menuitem value="Composants" url="/pagess/pagesComposant/Composant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-search"  />  
        <p:menuitem value="Dossier d'equivalence" url="DEQ.jsf" icon="ui-icon-document"  />  
    </p:tabMenu> 
    </h:form>
```

**How can I solve this problem knowing that should change automatically ?**

I Tray a managed bean it not work

```
public class LoginBean {
    private int activeindex=0;
public int getActiveindex() {
        return activeindex;
    }

    public void setActiveindex(int activeindex) {
        this.activeindex = activeindex;
    }  

   public void Dirige(int a){

       activeindex=a;
   }}..



<p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{loginBean.activeindex}" > 
        <p:menuitem value="Home" url="Menu.jsf" icon="ui-icon-star"  action="#{loginBean.Dirige(0)}"/>  
        <p:menuitem value="Fabricants" url="/pagess/pagesFabricant/Fabricant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-wrench" action="#{loginBean.Dirige(1)}"/>
    </p:menuitem>
```

also it not working

**I try to add update="@all" for everu menuitem .it is the same :(**

---

I forget To tell you .this component is on template page ..all page using this template 
!!!
the problem when the page is charged on the braowser it take the property of the template ,
on the template the code is

```
<h:form>
    <p:tabMenu activeIndex="0">
        <p:menuitem value="Home" url="Menu.jsf" icon="ui-icon-star" />
        <p:menuitem value="Fabricants" url="/pagess/pagesFabricant/Fabricant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-wrench"  />  
        <p:menuitem value="Composants" url="/pagess/pagesComposant/Composant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-search"  />  
        <p:menuitem value="Dossier d'equivalence" url="DEQ.jsf" icon="ui-icon-document"  />  
    </p:tabMenu> 
    </h:form>
```

It shows active index on 0 ,For that I thing all the page redirected not synchronize active index ..
Is there any solotion please

Answer (score 0):

I think is it only possible to update component tree inside action method.

You can modify components dynamicly inside action methods and set active index likewise.

Here is tabMenu component api for further references.

http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.5/org/primefaces/component/tabmenu/TabMenu.html

```
public void getFooClientId(int activeIndex) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();

    final String componentId = "foo";
    UIComponent c = findComponent(root, componentId);
    TabMenu t = (TabMenu)c;
    t.setActiveIndex(activeIndex);


  }

  /**
   * Finds component with the given id
   */
  private UIComponent findComponent(UIComponent c, String id) {
    if (id.equals(c.getId())) {
      return c;
    }
    Iterator<UIComponent> kids = c.getFacetsAndChildren();
    while (kids.hasNext()) {
      UIComponent found = findComponent(kids.next(), id);
      if (found != null) {
        return found;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```